# "404 not found" when directive uses template included by script type="text/ng-template"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, gulp

Strange problem. I've got gulp grabbing all the templates/partials HTML files and injecting them in `index.html` with a script wrapper like so:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/user/user.html">
    <div>Some html...</div>   
</script>
```

There's about 10 different templates being injected so far, one after another just like that, with the id pointing to the original file path (which is referenced throughout the AngularJS app in routes, directives, etc).

For some reason, the templates used by ngRoute are working. So when I switch pages, the template is loaded properly.

But when I go to a page that has directives that need to load a template, they are failing and returning "404 not found" errors.

Any ideas what's going on, or strategies on how I can debug this?

Angular version 1.3.3.

`ng-app="app"` is set on my `<html>` tag, and I'm injecting the text/ng-template code into the `<body>` section. I tried putting them in the `<head>` section before the script include for `app.js`, but that didn't help.

Comment: since you are using a relative path it might be trying to load the files from the wrong place. Have you tried putting a `/` in front of your paths, or setting a [base element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Comment: @PatrickEvans Ah, that's the problem! The other way around actually, the script tags didn't have a leading forward-slash, but the directives did have a leading forward-slash. So I edited the directive to remove the leading forward-slash and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to answer the question then @PatrickEvans or BuildTester1 :)

Comment: @PatrickEvans Actually in the end I added a leading slash everywhere because the directives couldn't find the template when I had removed it.